# React: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment

How can I fix this error being thrown?

> Error: CountryList(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Containers/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from '../Components/NavBar';
import SideBar from '../Components/SideBar';
import CountryList from '../Components/CountryList';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nations: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all%27)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(x => this.setState({ nations: x }));
  }

  render() {
    const { nations } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <SideBar>
          <CountryList nations={nations} />
        </SideBar>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: As the error is thrown from inside `CountryList`, you must add code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably does not return anything from CountryList component.
You should check your return statement. If you put any conditions for `nations` prop, maybe you did something wrong.
I guess you did like this.

```
CountryList extends React.Component{
  if(nations) {
     return nations.map(nation => ...)
  }
}
```

but you should do like this

```
 CountryList extends React.Component{
      if(nations) {
         return nations.map(nation => ...)
      } else {
         return null;
      }
    }
```

or better approach:

```
 CountryList extends React.Component{
     // ...do some stuff before return
     return (
         this.props.nations?.length > 0 && this.props.nations.map(....)
     )

     
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the return be inside render()?